# How to get parent table attributes from child model

Tags: node.js, inheritance, bookshelf.js

```
var ParentModel = bookshelf.Model.extend({ });
var ChildModel = ParentModel.extend({ });

new ChildModel().fetch().then(function(child){ 
    console.log(child.get('parentAttribute')); //undefined  
});
```

How can I get the inherited table attributes from the child object ?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I'm looking for a node module that supports table per inheritance.

Comment: Hi @JoshC. I have posted an answer, but we are out of luck = (

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately inheritance relationships are not supported by Bookshelf. In my post at the bookshelf forum I was suggested to use a plugin called Virtuals to simulate this behavior by adding getters and setters to the children models.

https://github.com/tgriesser/bookshelf/issues/612